# Optimization of sum of logs

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem of the form $$\operatorname*{argmax}_{\mathbf{w}} \sum_i \log(1 + \mathbf{w} \cdot \mathbf{k_i})$$ given some set of vectors, $\mathbf{ \{k_i\} }$. I have tried both gradient descent and BFGS, but both of them are slow. Is this a well known problem, and are there existing software implementations that can quickly solve a problem of this form?

Comment: $w,k_i\in \mathbb R^n$, what is $n$ and what range of $i$ ?

Comment: Without more detail it is hard to answer, do the $k_i$ satisfy some condition that will ensure that a maximum exists?

Comment: Did you try Newton's method (with a line search, of course)? Is it practical, given the size of the Hessian matrix or its structure?